# Creating Dynamic Header in Google sheet Obtained from Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-query

Please help. I have a google doc form that collects some data. I want to create the form such that the spreadsheet presents data as follows:

Name of user will be in a column across several rows, other columns will have dates as their header ;each of those dates will be the column header and the first column will remain constant.

So an example of this is: the first column contains the name of people, when they enter data such as weight, it will be recorded under column of today's date and if the same person enters weight in a week time, it will be recorded under another column with the date as the header, all these will be in the row that has the person name.

A picture of what I am trying to achieve is attached below.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible to achieve directly:

- **tabular form.** Forms store the information in a tabular form. Means each new response will appear in a separate row. Column 1 will contain timestamp
- **wide form.** When a table grows right is a called wide table.

Please see [this article](https://eagereyes.org/basics/spreadsheet-thinking-vs-database-thinking) as a good explanation of what I mean.

You may get the desired result with a help of `query` function.

`=query({'FormResponces'!B:C, arrayformula(int('FormResponces'!A:A)}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3")`

- `'FormResponces'!A:C` is a ref to your form responses
- B is a column with names
- C is a sum column
- A is a column with timestamps.

Comment: Hi Max, Thank you for your response. I will try the query and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Max, I have just tried this by putting the query in another sheet of the whole document, but it says "Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2 arguments.". Have I put the query in the right place?

Comment: `"Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA`. Please, check your formula again. It has extra commas inside arrayformula.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I put almost exactly the same formula you have in this page. The only different thing is your own formula is missing one bracket and I added that to mine. Also I placed this formula in a different sheet, not the sheet where the records are stored, is that how it should be? I added a picture of the formula in the main question please check it and see if I  have missed anything in it.

Comment: The case may be in regional settings, please try this syntax: =query({'FormResponces'!B:C \ arrayformula(int('FormResponces'!A:A)} ; "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3")

Comment: Hi Max, it doesn't still work. I have an example where I used array formular - =ArrayFormula(unique(if(int(A2:A)>0,int(A2:A),iferror(1/0)))). Also Am I placing the formular in the right place? I currently place it in a second sheet and not within the form response sheet.

Comment: Hi, @Kunbi, you could accept this answer (tick the green flag) and post another question and describe there your tries with a formula. This will engage other contributors, who might help you too.

Comment: Thanks Max, but accepting the answer means it solved your problem, however the problem isn't solved yet. I quite appreciate your help though. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was solving the original problem, posted as a question, and your last Q seems to be on your own formula, not mentioned in the answer, or the question.